# nginx rewrite everything that ends with / to index.html

Tags: nginx, redirect

I need to configure nginx to send everything that ends with / to /index.html. If it doesn't end with / then I want to show the file, for example I would want to show /img/asdf.jpg but I would want /img/ to redirect to /index.html. I thought I could do this with try_files but this isn't working:

```
 location / {
   try_files $uri /index.html;
 }
```

If I browse to http://atlas.ee.ops.about.com/asdf/ I see this in the access log:

```
X.X.X.X - - [13/Jun/2016:17:39:29 +0000] "GET /asdf/ HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0" "-"
```

How can I redirect to /index.html without prepending the path?

Comment: Could it be a stale browser cache causing the 304? Because it works for me as expected.

Comment: The problem is that my index.html has relative links. If I make a simple index.html with no links then it works, but as soon as I add a link it fails. I tried a bunch of different things and ended up doing this but I'm not sure this is the right way to do it:
 location ~ \/$
 {
  return 301 https://$host/index.html;
 }